# Python - Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype:

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I recently swapped over from requests to aiohttp because I couldn't use it in asyncio loops.

The swap went perfectly and everything goes well except for one thing. My console is full of

```
Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype:
```

and

```
Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: txt/html; charset=utf-8
```

My code has a list of sites it goes too and grabs JSON from, Each site is different but my loop is basically the same for each of them, Ive simplified it here:

```
PoolName = "http://website.com"
endpoint = "/api/stats"
headers = "headers = {'content-type': 'text/html'}" #Ive tried "application/json" and no headers
async with aiohttp.get(url=PoolName+endpoint, headers=headers) as hashrate:
                hashrate = await hashrate.json()
endVariable = hashrate['GLRC']['HASH']
```

It works perfectly, connects to the site grabs the json and sets endVariable correctly. but for some reason

```
Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype:
```

prints every time it goes through the loop. Which is annoying because it prints stats to the console and they get lost in the the errors each time it grabs a sites json

Is there a way to fix this error or to hide it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`aiohttp` is trying to [do the right thing and warn you](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/815#issuecomment-192895554) of incorrect `Content-Type`, which could at worst indicate that you are not getting JSON data at all, but something unrelated, such as the HTML content of an error page.

However, in practice many servers are misconfigured to *always* send the incorrect MIME type in their JSON responses, and JavaScript libraries apparently don't care. If you know you're dealing with such a server, you can always silence the warning by invoking `json.loads` yourself:

```
import json
# ...

async with self._session.get(uri, ...) as resp:
    data = await resp.read()
hashrate = json.loads(data)
```

Specifying `Content-Type` as you attempted makes no difference because it only affects the `Content-Type` of your *request*, whereas the problem lies in the `Content-Type` of the server's *response*, which is not under your control.

Answer (score 73):

Pass expected content type to `json()` method:

```
data = await resp.json(content_type='text/html')
```

or disable the check entirely:

```
data = await resp.json(content_type=None)
```

Comment: ➕1, I didn't know you could turn off the check or customize the expected header.

Comment: set content_type on the fly worked for me: `data = await resp.json(content_type=resp.content_type)`. But not sure if it is correct

Comment: Basically, it works in the same way as just `content_type=None`.