# Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html

Tags: python, json, discord.py, aiohttp

the meme command in my discord bot used to work earlier but it suddenly just stopped working....
here is the code

```
@commands.command(name = 'meme')
@commands.cooldown(1, 2, BucketType.user)
async def meme(self,ctx):
    '''get a random meme from reddit!'''
    subreddits = ['dankmemes', 'memes','meme', 'wholesomememes', 'comedyheaven','pewdiepiesubmissions', 'KidsAreFuckingStupid','cursedcomments','HolUp','blursedimages','rareinsults']
    subreddit = random.choice(subreddits)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get(f'https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            post=res['data']['children'][random.randint(0, 25)]
            url = post['data']['url']
            title= post['data']['title']
            embed = discord.Embed(title = title,description=f"Meme for {ctx.author}")
            embed.set_image(url=url)
            embed.set_footer(text = f'Image from r/{subreddit}')
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It stopped working some days ago.. I've been trying to find a solution for quite a while but couldn't get it to work
I tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48841071/16390831

Every solution I tried though, gave one of the two errors:
`aiohttp.client_exceptions.ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html', url=URL('https://www.reddit.com/r/meme/new.json?sort=hot')`

`File "C:\Users\dhrav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 167, in wrapped ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs) File "c:\Users\dhrav\Documents\Python Projects\SpaceBot\SpaceBot\commands.py", line 565, in meme res = json.loads(rs) File "C:\Users\dhrav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "C:\Users\dhrav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "C:\Users\dhrav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

What is wrong? is it something to do with the Reddit API?
I tried printing cs, it gave a weird output about servers and stuff

again, it did work a couple of days ago but stopped working suddenly, seemingly for no reason.
any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The API is returning a `Content-Type: text/html` header, you can pass `content_type=None` into `r.json` to ignore the header:

```py
res = await r.json(content_type=None)
```

Comment: Im having the same trouble, but then here is another error ```raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```

Comment: The API is returning nothing, an empty string @ChaoticNebula

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Reddit is sending the wrong content type. You can pass the expected content to the `json()` method

```py
res = await r.json(content_type='text/html')
```

Comment: hi MK, i actually tried this but it gave the second error mentioned...

Comment: @DhravyaShah: Check the content of your response ```r``` before parsing it. In my test,  it showed a 429 response, too many request. This might be caused by the headers sent with aiohttp. When using ```res = requests.get(f"https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/new.json?sort=hot",headers = {'User-agent': 'Test reddit script'})``` it works as soon as you set a User-Agent